# Stop external windows from being opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

A javascript file is included on my web page. This file is hosted on another server which I don't have access to and it opens new windows. That's what I want to stop. Is there any way to stop new windows from being opened?

Comment: not sure if this works or not, but try adding `<script>window.open = function() {};</script>` before that external javascript is loaded.

Comment: If you want to use `window.open` yourself at the same time as OneOfOne's fix, make a copy that will work for you and use that instead `var newWindow = Window.prototype.open.bind(window);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post this since it helped you:

Before the external script loads add : `window.open = function() {};`